# Count of work hours from time series using pandas

Tags: python, time, pandas, series

I have a csv file extracted from my windows pc:

```
date
16/07/2014 09:15:28
16/07/2014 09:15:22
16/07/2014 09:14:56
16/07/2014 09:14:50
16/07/2014 09:14:49
16/07/2014 09:14:46
16/07/2014 09:14:46
16/07/2014 09:14:46
16/07/2014 09:14:46
16/07/2014 09:14:46
16/07/2014 09:14:46
16/07/2014 09:14:46
15/07/2014 14:41:56
15/07/2014 14:41:47
15/07/2014 14:41:30
15/07/2014 14:39:58
15/07/2014 14:39:57
15/07/2014 14:39:54
15/07/2014 14:39:53
15/07/2014 14:39:49
```

I'd like to count the work hours per day but I did not find any function to split the time from the date and group it. Do you have any idea how to solve it? I also looked for it in google but I only found the count of objects.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify further with expected output. You can get the hour by doing `df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.hour())`

Comment: I got this error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hour'"

Comment: This means it's a string and not a datetime, convert it first `import pandas as pd df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfp'date'])`

Comment: I converted it into date time and I tried again but now I got this error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Comment: Can you edit the errors into your post including code

Comment: Sorry my mistake try: `df['hour']  = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)`, `hour` is an attribute not a method

Comment: In that case do you want me to post an answer or do you want to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your date values are strings, you can either convert it after loading:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

or better is to load it in as datetime in the first place:

```
In [144]:

df = pd.read_csv('time.csv', parse_dates=[0])
# now extract the hour by applying a lambda and accessing the hour attribute
df['hour']  = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df
Out[144]:
                  date  hour
0  2014-07-16 09:15:28     9
1  2014-07-16 09:15:22     9
2  2014-07-16 09:14:56     9
3  2014-07-16 09:14:50     9
4  2014-07-16 09:14:49     9
5  2014-07-16 09:14:46     9
6  2014-07-16 09:14:46     9
7  2014-07-16 09:14:46     9
8  2014-07-16 09:14:46     9
9  2014-07-16 09:14:46     9
10 2014-07-16 09:14:46     9
11 2014-07-16 09:14:46     9
12 2014-07-15 14:41:56    14
13 2014-07-15 14:41:47    14
14 2014-07-15 14:41:30    14
15 2014-07-15 14:39:58    14
16 2014-07-15 14:39:57    14
17 2014-07-15 14:39:54    14
18 2014-07-15 14:39:53    14
19 2014-07-15 14:39:49    14
```